# активируется venv, но по факту видит только глобальные библиотеки

Tags: python, windows, venv, poetry

Работаю в Windows 11 через обычный cmd.exe.
Раньше я работал в обыкновенном venv, все было хорошо. Потом я перешел на poetry все работало до какого то момента. На новом проекте устанавливал много библиотек, начал замечать что при poetry add он пишет что все установлено, в pyproject.toml и poetry.lock все зависимости писались, но по факту не устанавливалось. И я ставил через pip install. Теперь я понял что устанавливал глобально все, в тот момент виртуальное окружение не работало.
Теперь когда я запускаю хоть в старых проектах через venv\Scripts\activate хоть poetry shell в новых по факту ничего не активируется. Более того poetry shell как бы активируется только в последнем проекте, а в других проектах выдает ошибку:
Invalid value (at line 17, column 17)

Куда копнуть? Какие настройки посмотреть нужно, которые влияют на это? Возможно ли это из-за того что я реорганизовал папки с проектами и теперь они по другим путям лежат?

Comment: Во-первых, что значит «ничего не активируется»? Во-вторых, это полный текст ошибки?

Comment: "в pyproject.toml и poetry.lock все зависимости писались, но по факту не устанавливалось" - как вы определили, что не установилось? Запускали проект через poetry run ... или внутри poetry shell? poetry install запускать пробовали?

Comment: при активации нет никакой ошибки, отображается как будто работаю в виртуальном окружении, просто не видит установленные локальные библиотеки, только глобальные

Comment: "при активации" - как активировали, через poetry shell или "по-старинке" через activate?

Comment: например запускаю django через python manage.py runserver он выдает ошибку импортов (внутри poetry shell, которое запускается только на последнем проекте)

Comment: В общем, ничего не понятно. Сносите виртуальное окружение, делайте poetry install заново и пробуйте запускать еще раз, через poetry shell или `poetry run python manage.py runserver`

Comment: ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment? выдает ошибку импорта

Comment: если заглянуть в libs в venv там нет установленных пакетов

Comment: (d46-money-spy-py3.11) C:\Users\Олег\Python\ProjectsSrc\D46-Money-Spy>poetry install
The virtual environment found in C:\Users\╨Ю╨╗╨╡╨│\Python\ProjectsSrc\D46-Money-Spy\.venv seems to be broken.
Recreating virtualenv d46-money-spy in C:\Users\Олег\Python\ProjectsSrc\D46-Money-Spy\.venv
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 60 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

Comment: вот выдает такую ошибку каждый раз при poetry shell и каждый раз заново устанавливает пакеты, как при poetry install. По факту ничего не ставится. Ну или он устанавливает в глобальные библиотеки

Comment: Как вариант - попробуйте перенести проект в директорию без кириллицы в пути. И Python желательно тоже, если он вдруг в директории пользователя установлен.

Comment: да, получилось, я увидел что в .venv в Lib установились пакеты, но с другим проектом, который я тоже скопировал по пути без кириллицы выдает ошибку Invalid value (at line 17, column 17) при активации poetry shell

Comment: Во втором проекте сносите виртуальное окружение и делайте poetry install заново (т.к. вы ничего не пишете, что вы делали или не делали с виртуальным окружением, я предполагаю, что вы вместо со старым .venv перенесли)

Comment: все, нашел в чем ошибка была - pyproject.toml был некорректный, я его исправил и все заработало! Благодарю Вас за уделенное время и помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Сложилась такая же ситуация — виртуальная среда активирована, но при этом интерпретатор и менеджер пакетов (в моём случае 'pip') использовались глобальные (случилось только не на Windows, а на Mac). И, в принципе, автор вопроса сам на него ответил, упомянув о "реорганизации" проекта с перемещением рабочих каталогов. У меня некорректная работа была вызвана переименованием проекта (хотя и не исключаю, что тоже перемещал) вне IDE, то есть **без рефакторинга проекта**.

Собственно, вот она причина, а решение простое (в моём случае): удалил папку с виртуальной средой, и настроил её — среду — заново.